# Existence of stationary process with a given ACF

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, covariance-matrix

Consider the sequence
$$\gamma(\tau) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } |\tau| ≤ K \\
0 & \text{if }|\tau| > K
\end{cases}$$
where $K$ is a positive integer. Is $\gamma(\tau)$ an auto covariance sequence for some discrete parameter stationary process $Y_t$ ?

The answer is no but I don't see any valid argument. This would correspond to a process with a Toepliz matrix with ones on the diagonal and the $K$ sub diagonals near it and I can arrange myself to define a process with such a matrix.

Does this mean that if a process is stationary then it has a Toeplitz covariance matrix but the converse is not true ?

Comment: Consider what it means for $\gamma(1)=1$ in a stationary process: you must have $Y_{t+1}=\alpha+\beta Y_t$ for all $t$ (and $\beta\ne 0$). What does that imply about $\gamma(n)$ for any $n$?  (The role of a "discrete parameter ... process" is obscure and seems to be irrelevant.  Maybe you intend that $\tau$ be limited to a lattice? If so, wlg you can take $\tau\in\mathbb Z.$) Another way to analyze this is to consider the eigenvalues of your Toeplitz matrix: at least one will be *negative.*

Comment: @whuber "Discrete parameter" means that the time index $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ (as opposed to $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the continuous case).  It is a quite standard terminology in stochastic process.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you.  It's also standard terminology to use "parameter" for the variables determining a family of distributions or processes.  Given the reference to an *integral* $K,$ the use of "parameter" to refer to $t$ otherwise looked superfluous; and the evident collection of examples supporting a "no" answer made me wonder whether there were some special unstated parametric assumptions in effect, whence my request for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that such a stationary process does not exist, it suffices to show that $\gamma$ is not non-negative definite (see Definition 1.5.1 and Theorem 1.5.1 of *Time Series: Theory and Methods* by Brockwell and Davis), which can be shown by demonstrating the covariance matrix $\Gamma$ of $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_{K + 2})$ is not non-negative definite. By assumption, the order $3$ matrix $\Gamma$ equals to
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
It is easy to verify that the determinant of this matrix is $-1$, hence it cannot be non-negative definite (here we used the fact that if a matrix is PSD, then its determinant must be non-negative).

To put in a more comprehensible way, consider the linear combination $X = Y_1 - Y_2 + Y_{K + 2}$. Under the assumption, the variance of $X$ is $1 + 1 + 1 - 2 - 2 = -1 < 0$, which is absurd.